# WinSCP alternative for OS X (that supports sudo and without virtualizing WinSCP)

Tags: mac-osx, scp, graphical-user-interface

I recently switched from administering my systems using Windows to OS X.   I've found really nice alternatives to damn near everything I used previously, however I have not found a nice GUI editor (sometimes VIM just hurts my face for long scripting jobs) that can transfer files over SCP and that is sudo-aware.

WinSCP did all these things previously for me, Allowed me to log in, edit a file locally, and every time I save, it sends the file to the remote server.   It also gave me the ability to sudo edit files, so I was able to edit files not owned by my primary user without having to sudo chown a million files just to change them back.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried Cyberduck?

http://cyberduck.ch/

I'm not sure if it allows for sudo integration as I don't use a Mac (this isn't, to my knowledge, something that is native to the SCP protocol; i suspect winSCP does it by initiating a separate shell session, sudo chowning the files, and chowning them back after the operation is complete).

Comment: Yea, doesn't do sudo. :/

Comment: My main issue with Cyberduck has been that I can't save connections to be able to reconnect easily.

Comment: I don't see SCP support at all with Cyberduck?

Comment: SCP support was dropped from Cyberduck in 2015. https://trac.cyberduck.io/ticket/8895

Answer (score 1):

[Fugu](http://rsug.itd.umich.edu/software/fugu/) will do SCP/SFTP in a fairly nice, albeit simple GUI. It will launch your local OS X editor to edit files on the server and then automatically sync the file to the remote server when you save it within the editor. I don't think Fugu fulfills your sudo requirement, however.

Comment: Yea, doesn't do sudo. :/

Comment: And depending on which editor you use it may or may not save edited files back to the remote machine, no matter how you have it configured. :(

Comment: Fugu supports coping files between ssh server and smb share, exactly what I need, thanks!

Comment: "You cannot install or run Fugu because PowerPC applications are no longer supported", says my OS X.

Answer (score -1):

WinSCP port for Mac is the only solution for a while.
<del>http://portingteam.com/index.php/files/file/7089-winscp/</del>

At this time, none of Mac SCP GUI clients doesn't do sudo.

Comment: its download links are dead.